# Node.js Active handles rise suddenly

Tags: node.js, parse-server

I have a `Parse Server` which is a `Node.js` + `express` wrapper for a mobile app (about 100 simultaneous users every day), hosted on DigitalOcean. The app server communicates with MongoDB, which is hosted on another droplet of DigitalOcean. I'm using `pm2` as a process manager and its monitoring tool, which is web-based. On the same process, we operate `LiveQuery`, a WebSocket server made by the Parse community as well.

The thing is, I've been having some performance issues with the server. Everything works smoothly, until the Active handles rise up uncontrollably! (see the image below) It's like after one point the server says "I'm done! Now I rest!"

Usually the active handles stay between 30 to 70. The moment I restart the process with `pm2 restart` everything goes back to normal!

I've been having this issue for quite some time now and I haven’t been able to figure out what’s causing it! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

**EDIT:** I did a stress test where I created 200 LiveQuery sockets for 1 user, instead of 2 that a user normally has and there was a spike of 300 active handles, for like 5 seconds! The moment the sockets were all created, everything went back to normal!

Comment: Did you find any solution? Is it pm2?

Comment: I am facing the same issue.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59861542/active-handles-in-the-simple-nodejs-request-keeps-increasing-exponentially but haven't found any solution yet

Comment: Unfortunately I haven’t found why it's happening! As a temporary solution I created a `cron job` that automatically restarts the Nodejs server every 15 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

I usually use restart based on memory usage

```
pm2 start filename.js --max-memory-restart 160 --exp-backoff-restart-delay=100
```

pm2 has also built-in cron job or autostart script setup in case the server ever restarts, see https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/

*it would be could if pm2 would provide restart options based on active connections or heap memory*