# Active handles in the simple Nodejs Request keeps increasing exponentially

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pm2

I have written a simple node API whose sole purpose is just to notify the user that the internet is alive. I am hitting this API after every 3 seconds and it works fine till the active handles are around 4000 or less but after then my server stops responding till the time I restart the server. I am running this server through pm2. I have attached a link to the image of my server when I type "pm2 monit".Link - https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEgUd.png

```
const express = require('express');
        const app = express();
        app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
            res.set("Connection", "close");
            res.send({status:200, message:'request received'}).end();
        });

        app.listen(5005, () => {
          console.log('Listening on port 5005');
        });
```

Comment: You can see that the Active handles keep on increasing exponentially. I am not able to figure out what's wrong in the code. I have used pm2 for many projects but this is the first time I am facing this issue.

Comment: try this package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running

Comment: @AshishModi- Have you faced this issue before?

Comment: I haven't faced myself but this package helps you to figure out what you are looking for

Comment: Does it check for all the ports where node service is running